# Android Custom Search View with MultiAutoComplete Text View

Tags: android, android-edittext, searchview, multiautocompletetextview

I want to achieve this type to search box in my application.
Only issue is that I want to use my own custom MultiAutoComplete TextView in the Edit Text.

So how do I handle this.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to set a custom auto-complete adapter? or a custom looking search box?

Comment: @Frank Custom Auto-Complete adapter

Comment: Its that instead of SearchView's default edittext , I have a custom MultiAutoComplete text view that I want to set.

Comment: So not the look, just the autocomplete functionality?
Check this:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: @Frank I want the design and look to be like SearchView (as in the picture) and also want functionality of my MultiAutoComplete View

Comment: Ok. I dont know how to "design" one but the link I sent should help you get started with tweaking the functionality.